# Batch SET /A in for loop breaks loop variables

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, set

I have this batch script which is supposed to enumerate all files in a directory:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /A cn=0
SET cwd=%~dp0

ECHO Files:
FOR %%I IN (%cwd%\*) DO (
    SET /A cn=cn+1
    ECHO !cn!
    IF "%%I"=="buthow" ()
    ECHO %%~nxI
)
EXIT /B 0
```

Say we have the document `d1.txt`, `d2.txt`, `d3.txt` in the folder. The code above works as expected, but when I remove the if statement which does nothing(?), I get the following output:

```
1
d1.txt
2
cnd2.txt
3
cnd3.txt
```

Why is that?

Comment: The code have _two_ ECHO commands: the `ECHO !cn!` that should show the value of `cn` variable, and `ECHO %%~nxI` that should show the name and extension of each file, so the output you show prove that the code "works as expected" (without the strange `if` command).

Comment: Can you possibly get any more sloppy!? The posted code "works as expected" ?!?!  I think not, as there is a fatal syntax error with your IF statement. But the output without the IF is exactly as it should be.

Comment: No. The expected output would have been with `d2.txt` instead of `cnd2.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Read `if /?`

> ```
> Performs conditional processing in batch programs.
>
> IF [NOT] ERRORLEVEL number command
> IF [NOT] string1==string2 command
> IF [NOT] EXIST filename command
>
>   NOT               Specifies that Windows should carry out
>                     the command only if the condition is false.
>
>   ERRORLEVEL number Specifies a true condition if the last program run
>                     returned an exit code equal to or greater than the number
>                     specified.
>
>   string1==string2  Specifies a true condition if the specified text strings
>                     match.
>
>   EXIST filename    Specifies a true condition if the specified filename
>                     exists.
>
>   command           Specifies the command to carry out if the condition is
>                     met.  Command can be followed by ELSE command which
>                     will execute the command after the ELSE keyword if the
>                     specified condition is FALSE
>
> The ELSE clause must occur on the same line as the command after the IF.
> ```

**Note that `()` is not a valid command:**

```
==> if 1==2 ()
) was unexpected at this time.

==> if 1==1 ()
) was unexpected at this time.

==> ()
) was unexpected at this time.

==>
```

Comment: It might be that WINE interprets it a bit differently, I can not test on Windows but there is not (unexpected) difference in output when I fill it with an ECHO or PAUSE statement. The question was rather where would the additional `cn`s at the beginning of file names come from?

Comment: Please add `ECHO ON` just before `FOR %%I …` line; contact WINE's [Bugzilla Bug Tracker](https://bugs.winehq.org/). Please add `wine` tag to your question using [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36516508/edit) link. However, `(echo(>NUL)` statement would _do nothing_ rather than syntactically wrong `()`.